# создать свой тип на основе numeric

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет,
Хотел создать свой тип на основе numeric:

```
CREATE TYPE Type_Money AS numeric(10,2);
```

но получил ошибку...

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Comment: вставьте текст ошибки в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите создать тип данных как простое описание базового типа, плюс, например с ограничениями CHECK, то вам нужен [`create domain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html), а не `create type`. Например:

```
CREATE DOMAIN amountp AS numeric(10, 2) CHECK (VALUE >= 0.);
```

Для создания типа `amountp` с фиксированной запятой и только положительными значениями. И теперь это имя можно использовать в таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    /**/
    amount amountp NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    /**/
);
```

CHECK не обязателен, можно сделать

```
CREATE DOMAIN amount AS numeric(10, 2);
```

Тогда тип будет принимать и отрицательные значения тоже.

`create type` - это для композитных типов, `enum` и `range`. Базовый скалярный тип объявить тоже может, но весьма низкоуровневым способом. На тот случай, если вы захотите написать расширение на `C` со своим типом данных и какой-то своей логикой.